# Dynamic broadcast receiver in multiple activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm baffled at the lack of documentation for this typical scenario. I have 4 activities in my Android app - A, B, C, and D. I register a WiFi P2p broadcast receiver in Activity A. Once connected, the user can switch between Activities B, C and D, and may leave/kill the app by pressing the home button/killing from recent apps menu. Where should I unregister the broadcast receiver? In a single activity, you would register in the onResume() method and unregister in onPause(). What about multiple activities? It doesn't seem quite right to me that I may have to register and unregister for every activity.

Relevant code :

```
// helper class method called by Activity A by passing its context.
private void registerReceiver(Context context) {
    context.registerReceiver(p2pBroadcastReceiver, p2pIntentFilter);
}
```

Sorry if this sounds too simple, please direct me to the right documentation/link!

Answer (score 1):

As you start the activities B,C and D you can unregister broadcast receiver in the lifecycle call back methods in those respective activities B,C and D.

For example In your Activity B you can unregister the broadcast receiver in the onPause method of Activity B

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SmsBR();
 public void onPause() 
   {
     super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
   }
}
```

The Android Framework will still call all the lifecycle callback methods even if the application gets killed by system or the user. So if you unregister in onPause() it will get called when activity goes to background or gets killed.

Comment: So you're saying I should register in the onresume and unregister in the onpause of every Activity?

Comment: I don't know your application activity flow but one scenario would be, if you have activities started in this order A ->B->C->D, so the tasks backstack has Activity D as head activity which is first poped and its lifecycle callback methods are called. if you unregister in activity D it is enough as you don't need to unregister in Activity C, Activity B and then in Activity A. For your particular use case know which activity is popped first or where you need to unregister based on the functionality of the activity itself.

Comment: The activity flow is, the user starts of in A to find a peer to connect to, and once connected over WiFi Direct, moves to Activity B, using it as the menu activity. From there, the user can move about to C and D. I register in A, and ideally, I'd really only like to unregister the broadcast receiver when he quits the application.

Comment: @CrearoRotar as you are registering it in Activity A it is the appropriate place to Unregister, because if you have some functionality in Activity C that needs receiver it will still work even if Activity D is destroyed. simple rule of thumb would be draw the task backstack for your use case and check if you need broacast receiver in all of those if answer is yes then unregister in the backstacks last activity(tail) or unregister in Activity where you think the next activities in the back stack doesn't need the receiver. If this helps mark this answer as accepted, useful for other users.

Comment: @CrearoRotar refer this [backstack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) documentation

Comment: Hold on! (thanks for your time, btw). I understand what you're saying, but I can't unregister in A itself -- when I `startActivity(A.this, B.class)`, if I unregister in the onpause/onstop of A, B won't be able to listen to any of the broadcasts. A, B, C, and D all have to listen to this broadcast.

Comment: Right, but I'm asking particularly for dynamic BRs with multiple activities -- here's the catch. Post Android N, you can't declare WiFi/Connectivity broadcast receiver in the manifest - it has to be done dynamically. I've +1ed your inputs for your time, but this still hasn't answered my question.

Comment: Yep you are right also one thing you can do is register/unregister in every activity that needs BR this doesn't leak context out of activity, just debug and play with it thats how we learn.

Comment: Right, that's what I've done in my current implementation, and am using it as the last resort is to register/unregister in every activity, but that just doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: don't worry this operation doesn't use much of the resources so we can register/unregister multiple time in multiple places. Another way is to register/unregister in a background service, let me know what you have done with this use case.

Comment: @CrearoRotar i have found this when going through the android documentation for global state management hope this will help you.
[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
Note: There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situations, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), include Context.getApplicationContext() as a Context argument when invoking your singleton's getInstance() method.